# samba shares - cannot see files content

Tags: samba

[image]Hello,
I have below issue,
I have a lot of samba shares and cannot see files (images) content.
Is it possible to do something with it ?

Comment: I think you mean not seeing *thumbnails*, right? The default setting for Files is to show a preview only for local files. It can be changed in preferences > preview

Comment: hello, can You please show me how to do it ? In  KDE inside preview I don't see this.

Comment: This is a good example of why it's important to include Ubuntu release and flavor in the questions. I assume standard Ubuntu with Gnome's default file manager - Files, formerly known as Nautilus -, Kubuntu's Dolphin is a different program. Check preferences. It probably has a similar one.

Comment: Hello,
Definetily I agree with You, everytime it should be provided OS Version and x-interface used.
Regarding my question I have checked and Nautilus after change preview settings correctly viewing previews, but Dolphin not.
Can someone help me what can I do with it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your file manager go to: Edit >> Preferences >> Preview.

Where it is with the option: "Local Files Only" change it to "Yes" as shown in the image below.

[view thumbnail of images on computers on the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUssK.png)

Note that in some cases you have the option to select to view thumbnails smaller than xx megabytes.